# WPF How to simply updating the UI from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem when I used to Update a UI from another Class;

This is my Situation.

First I have this class called PersonalData

```
namespace WPF_APPLICATION

public class PersonalData
{       
    private string iDNumber;
    private string firstName;        

    public PersonalData()
    {            
       
    }       

    public string IDNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return iDNumber;
        }

        set
        {
            iDNumber = value;
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        set
        {
            firstName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And PersonalData was created by a FirstPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace WPF_APPLICATION

public partial class FirstPage 
{
    
    PersonalData person;
   
    public FirstPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
        person = new PersonalData();
        person.IDNumber = "1659880";
    }
    
    private void firstBTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        person.Firstname = "John";
    }
    
}
```

and all I want is I want the Object person that created by FirstPage.xaml.cs will go to Update UI to another page (Such as SeconePage.xaml, ThirdPage.xaml) every time button clicked or property changed.

I've tried an INotifyPropertyChanged but it doesn't work, maybe I missed some concept of WPF.

This is my SeconePage.xaml that I've tried.

```
<Page x:Class="WPF_APPLICATION.SeconePage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_APPLICATION"
  xmlns:m="clr-namespace:WPF_APPLICATION"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="240" d:DesignWidth="1080"
  Title="ScalePage">
<Page.Resources>        
    <m:PersonalData x:Key="myperson"/>       
</Page.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource myperson}}" Background="#eee">
    <TextBox x:Name="Value1" Text="{Binding IDNumber}"/>
   
    <TextBox x:Name="Value2" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Margin="0,40"/>
</Grid>

</Page>
```

and Personal Class that Implement INotifypropertyChanged

```
 namespace WPF_APPLICATION

public class PersonalData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{       
    private string iDNumber;
    private string firstName;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        
    
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public PersonalData()
    {            
       
    }       

    public string IDNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return iDNumber;
        }

        set
        {
            iDNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IDNumber");
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        set
        {
            firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You xaml code would help and how did you used INotifyPropertyChanged? Just a hint: you should get familiar with MVVM.

Comment: I've add my code.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an ok solution and you can go with it BUT it is **NOT** the best way to solve your problem.

### 1. Open a new Window

To open a new *Window* you need an instance of the *View* for ex.:

```
SeconePage seconePage = new SeconePage();
```

Now you are able to make the new *Window*  appear with the following code:

```
seconePage.Show();
```

## 2. Perform code from step 1 OnPropertyChanged()

First create new Variable for the current Window:

```
public int currentWindow = 1;
```

Then create a method for the *Windows* you want to show for ex.:

```
 public void ShowNextWindow(int window)
    {
        switch (window)
        {
            case 2:
            SeconePage seconePage = new SeconePage();
            seconePage.Show();
            currentWindow += 1;
                break;
            case 3:
                ThirdPage thirdPage = new ThirdPage();
                thirdPage.Show();
                currentWindow += 1;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Now go to your *Personal Class* and add `ShowNextWindow();` to your setter. It should look something like this:

```
public string IDNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return iDNumber;
        }

        set
        {
            iDNumber = value;
            ShowNextWindow(currentWindow);
            OnPropertyChanged("IDNumber");
        }
    }
```

Now if the value changes the next *Window* will be displayed.

## 3. Perform code from step 1 on Button.click()

Just perform `ShowNextWindow(currentWindow);` on the button which should switch the view.